# Fixed header with flex design

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a fixed header with a flex design. But when I add the property `position: fixed` the next div is no more after the header but goes under the header (I don't want to add a `margin-top` to it)

Here's my code:

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.header_container{
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}    

.main_container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #CB6115;
    flex-grow: 1; //to use all the space of the screen
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header_container">header</div>
    <div class="main_container">main</div>
</div>
```

What should I add to have it proper?

Comment: "I don't want to add a margin-top to it", thats the most clean fix... Could you explain why you don't want to use that?

Comment: then make it sticky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the `fixed` to `sticky` and this will make it fixed when you scroll until then it will behave normal.

look at the code it is working fine without the `margin-top`;

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.header_container{
    background-color: grey;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}    

.main_container{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #CB6115;
    flex-grow: 1; //to use all the space of the screen
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header_container">header</div>
    <div class="main_container">main</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, honestly, I didn't know this "sticky" possibility. It's perfect :)